# Python: How can I tell if my python has SSL?

Tags: python, ssl

How can I tell if my source-built python has SSL enabled?  either

- after running configure, but before compiling (best).
- after compiling, when I can run the python.

Context:

- a script that populates a bare linux box.
- Prerequisite is to install openssl, so that Python can do https.
- trying to detect if this prerequisite is not met.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If all you want to do is figure out if `openssl` is installed, you can parse the output of `openssl version`:

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016
```

You can get [all sorts of information](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/version.html) from `version`, for example, the directory where its stored:

```
$ openssl version -d
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
```

As far as Python goes, I'm not sure how you can tell before running configure (maybe check the contents of `config.log`?) but once Python is installed; simply parse the output of `ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION`, like this:

```
$ python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"
OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016
```

For even more information, have a play with the `sysconfig` module, for example:

```
$ python -c "import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_config_var('CONFIG_ARGS'))"
'--enable-shared' '--prefix=/usr' '--enable-ipv6' '--enable-unicode=ucs4' '--with-dbmliborder=bdb:gdbm' '--with-system-expat' '--with-computed-gotos' '--with-system-ffi' '--with-fpectl' 'CC=x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' 'CFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security ' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro'
```

Comment: // , `python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"` worked perfectly. I was able to tell that my `python` had SSL, but the result for `python3 -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"` was a `ModuleNotFoundError`. Thanks, @Burhan